# sed: extracting value of a key-value pair in a URL query string

Tags: command-line, sed, url, parsing

I am trying to use sed to extract the value part of one of the many key-value pairs in a URL's query string

This is what I am trying:

```
echo 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abc&g=xyz' | sed 's@^https?://(www.)?youtube.com/(watch\\?)?.*?v(=|/)([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]*)(&.*)?$@$4@'
```

but it always outputs the input URL as is.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update 1**

To clarify some issues:

1. The regex is more complicated than it has to be because I am also trying to check the validity of the input and generate the output only if the input is valid. So a stricter match.
2. The desired output is the value of the key 'v' in the query string.
3. Have been unable to find the version of `sed` that I am using, but it's the one that comes with Mac OS X (10.7.5).
4. In my version of `sed` $1, $2 etc. seem to be the matches, \1, \2 etc. give the error:
   `sed: 1: "s@^https?://(www.)?yout ...": \4 not defined in the RE` ***Not correct!** as I found out later. Apologies for causing the confusion.*

**Update 2**

Have updated the `sed` RE to make it more specific based on suggestion by @slhck below, but the issue remains as before.

**Update 3**

Based on the `man` page for this version of `sed` it appears that this is a BSD-flavoured version.

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: @Endoro I can only guess since the regex here is more complicated than it has to be, but I'd say since the OP wants the fourth capture group, they want everything between `v=` and the next `&`, so the video ID.

Comment: @Endoro: I've answered both points in the update to the original question above. Thanks for seeking the clarification.

Comment: @markvgti -- If you continue to make questions please clarify soever, what OS and other programs you use.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Even simpler, if you just want the `abc`:

```
 echo 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abc&g=xyz' | awk -F'[=&]' '{print $2}'
```

If you want the `xyz` :

```
echo 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abc&g=xyz' | awk -F'[=&]' '{print $4}'
```

---

EXPLANATION:

- `awk` : is a scripting language that automatically processes input files line by line, splitting each line into fields. So, when you process a file with `awk`, for each line, the first field is `$1`, the second `$2` etc up to `$N`. By default `awk` uses blanks as the field separator.
- `-F'[=&]'` : `-F` is used to change the field delimiter from spaces to something else. In this case, I am giving it a [*class*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes) of characters. Square brackets (`[ ]`) are used by many languages to denote groups of characters. So, specifically, `-F'[=&]'` means that `awk` should use both `&` and `=` as field delimiters.
- Therefore, given the input string from your question, using `&` and `=` as delimiters, `awk` will read the following fields:

  ```
  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abc&g=xyz
  |----------- $1 -------------| --- - ---      
                                  |  |  |
                                  |  |  ̣----- $4
                                  |  -------- $3
                                  ----------- $2
  ```

  So, all you need to do is print whichever one you want `{print $4}`.

---

You said you also want to check that the string is a valid youtube URL, you can't do that with `sed` since if it does not match the regex you give it, it will simply print the entire line. You can use a tool like `Perl` to only print if the regex matches:

```
echo 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abc&g=xyz' | 
  perl -ne 's/http.*www.youtube.com\/watch\?v=(.+?)&.+/$1/ && print'
```

Finally, to simply print `abc` you can use the standard UNIX tool [`cut`](http://ss64.com/osx/cut.html):

```
echo 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abc&g=xyz' | 
  cut -d '=' -f 2 | cut -d '&' -f 1
```

Comment: Cool, this works! Phew! On the downside this means I'll have to learn to use `awk` now :-(... thanks, but I am going to hold off on marking this as the accepted answer, in the hopes that with help I can debug `sed`. Many, many thanks though.

Comment: @markvgti Thing is `sed` is not the best tool for the job when it comes to capturing patterns, it is extremely powerful and fast and it _can_ do it but it's more complicated than necessary. I added an explanation of how the `awk` command works, you might find it easier to understand now. I also added a `Perl` and a `cut` solution just for the sake of completeness :).

Comment: I have marked your answer as the accepted one, even though it wasn't a direct answer to my question. Your answer explained so much and provided so much knowledge that I thought it worthy of highlighting. Thanks! Using `sed` was essentially a case of "If all you have is a hammer, every problem looks like a nail" -- was reluctant to learn One More New Thing but `awk` seems fairly easy and so perhaps worth the time investment.

Comment: @markvgti in the *nix world, you never just have a hammer, all *nix systems will have sed, awk and perl installed.

Answer (score 2):

If you really just want the video ID – so, anything between `v=` and the next `&` – just use:

```
sed -r 's/.*v=([[:alnum:]]*).*/\1/'
```

Here's what's wrong with your command:

- The `-r` is needed to use extended regular expressions. If you leave that out, `sed` interprets the parentheses literally, so there won't be any match groups. With BSD `sed`, use the `-E` option instead.
- You use `$1` to refer to matches, but you should use `\1`. `$1` is actually a shell argument passed to the current script, for example.
- You should use a character class like `[[:alnum:]]` (or `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` depending on how the IDs are set up) to match the parameter value, since otherwise the next `&` will be captured as well. The regex is greedy and will just match `abc&g=xyz` if you use `.*?`, since lazy quantification is not supported in BRE/ERE, and only in Perl regex or other "modern" flavors.

Comment: As in the update above, 1) haven't been able to find sed version, and 2) \1, \2 etc. throws errors. This version of `sed` says that `-r` is an illegal argument.

Comment: even when I changed the `(.*?)` of the desired match to `([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]*)` (since this value is Base64 encoded), it still doesn't work. Good suggestion on making the match more specific though.

Answer (score 2):

if you need "xyz" try this (GNU sed):

```
echo 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abc&g=xyz' | sed 's/.*=\([[:alnum:]]*\).*/\1/'
```

Comment: Beware that the `\w` is not POSIX compatible, so this command isn't portable.

Comment: You are right, I changed it to `[[:alnum:]]`, thanks!

Comment: @Endoro Your answer put me on the right path (thanks!) and I was able to come up with the desired `sed` command (though I needed something more specific than `[[:alnum:]]`) and will be adding it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Experimenting with `sed` based off the answers given by @Endoro and @slhck led me to the final answer (the one I wanted).  This is what works for me with the version of `sed` on Mac OS X (10.7.5):

```
echo 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dnCkNz_xrpg' | sed -E 's@https?://(www\.)?youtube.com/(watch\?).*v=([-_a-zA-Z0-9]*).*@\3@'
```

*Explanation:*

1. `-E` is to make `sed` use extended RE. In other versions of `sed` `-r` may be the equivalent option.
2. The seemingly more-complicated-than-it-needs-to-be RE is to also verify that this is a valid YouTube link. Modify the beginning parts of this RE as required (e.g., `https?://(www\.)?example.com/(.*\?).*key=([^&]*).*`)
3. The `\3` matches the 3rd expression in parentheses and prints it out as the answer/match (which is what I want).
4. Using 's@@@' instead of the usual 's///' so that I don't have to escape the many forward slashes (`\`) in a URL.

Hope this helps others too as I have been helped.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, `-E` is  the BSD `sed` option for extended regular expressions, so I take it you're on OS X? `-r` is used for GNU `sed` which is standard on Linux.

Comment: @slhck Yes, as I mentioned in Update 1 to my question, I am on OS X (10.7.5).

Comment: Didn't see your edit. Glad you got it figured out!

Answer (score 0):

It always display the URL because SED is not matching it.

```
    echo 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abc&g=xyz' | sed 's!^http://www.youtube.com/watch\?\(.*=.*\)&\(.*=.*\)!\1!'
```

Will display
v=abc